# Is the ''proof" for a proposition about slowly varying function correct?

Tags: real-analysis, slowly-varying-functions

The positive function $f: [0,+\infty)\to\mathbb{R}^+$ is called slowly varying function if
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{f(cx)}{f(x)}=1 \text{ for any $c>0$}. $$
Now there is a ''proof" for this proposition: Let $f$ be a slowly varying function, for every $r>0$ ,
$$\int_x^{\infty}t^{-r-1}f(t)\text{d}t\sim \frac{1}{r}x^{-r}f(x) \text{ as }x\to +\infty.$$
*Proof*.  For every $c>0$ and $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a positive number $X$ such taht
\begin{equation}\label{1}
1-\varepsilon<\frac{f(cx)}{f(x)}<1+\varepsilon \text{ as } x>X.
\end{equation}
We take $c=t/x$ and have
$$(1-\varepsilon)f(x)<f(t)<(1+\varepsilon)f(x).$$
So
$$r(1-\varepsilon)f(x)\int_x^{\infty}t^{-r-1}\text{d}t<r\int_x^{\infty}t^{-r-1}f(t)\text{d}t<r(1+\varepsilon)f(x)\int_x^{\infty}t^{-r-1}\text{d}t.$$
This means that
$$(1-\varepsilon)x^{-r}f(x)<r\int_x^{\infty}t^{-r-1}f(t)\text{d}t<(1+\varepsilon)x^{-r}f(x).$$
For the arbitrariness of $\varepsilon$ we can assert the validity of this proposition. This is the end of the proof. But
I can't sure the above ''proof" is right. I belive that the $\varepsilon$ is related to $c$. So we can not take
$c=t/x$ since $t>x$, both $t$ and $x$ are variables.
Is my view correct? How to prove this proposition?

Comment: This looks like the same logic as epsilon-delta definitions. The proof seems fine.

Comment: You are correct to be concerned; this "proof" is not correct. The trouble is that $X$ depends upon $c$, and the inequalities are used under the integral sign for arbitrarily large values of $c=t/x$ with no guarantee that $x$ is larger than the corresponding $X$.   From what I recall, a correct proof makes use of a derived power-law bound with small exponent, something like $f(t)\le (1+\epsilon)f(x)(t/x)^\delta$, valid for all $t>x$ large enough.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you write a detailed "correct" proof for me? I'v being troubled by this problem for days.